# Login with facebook not working third time onwards

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

My application has two login options, gplus and facebook.

Steps:
1. Login with facebook (abc@gmail.com) - ok, then logout.

2. Login with gmail (xyz@gmail.com)    - ok, then logout.
3. Login with facebook (abc@gmail.com) - ok, then logout.
4. Login with gmail (xyz@gmail.com)    - ok, then logout.
5. Login with facebook (abc@gmail.com) - **No error, the page where they ask for " You have already gave permission....." is seen for a second then close by itself. And app goes back to the login page.**
6. Login with gmail (xyz@gmail.com)    - ok, then logout.
7. Login with facebook (abc@gmail.com) - same issue as 5.
8. Login with facebook (abc@gmail.com) - same issue as 5.
9. Login with gmail (xyz@gmail.com)    - ok, then logout.

The above steps were tested in two devices. And the issue is seen only in one of the device.

The other device has no issue.
Both the device have Facebook-Lite and Facebook Messenger app installed.

What could be the cause of issue?

For Login

```
LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(mFBCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            getFBUserInfo(loginResult);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // Log "Login attempt canceled.
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            // Log  "Login attempt failed."
        }
    });
```

For Logout:

```
if (null != AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() && null != Profile.getCurrentProfile()) {           
        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, once you have given permission through Facebook and try to re-authenticate, the dialog will flash for a second and disappear because you have already given permission.

Look at the list of applications in your Facebook profile:
https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications

Logging out does not remove this authenticated app from the list, it simply ends the current session. Next time you try to authenticate Facebook detects that this app already has permission, flashes the dialog and moves on.

Comment: But that is not the issue here, I was just describing how my app is behaving. Issue is why am I not able to login from 3rd time onwards?

Comment: What makes you think you're not logged in? The only issue you described is that the auth window quickly flashes. You have not included any code that retrieves account information and fails to do so after third attempt nor anything else. Include more code and details; I'm glad to help.